# AngularJS how can socketio return value to nest function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I'm new on AngularJS and I would like to know how I could be able for force the data of my state use the value which is sent by socket.io callback. Thanks

```
t.state(e.state + ".contact", {
      url: "/contact/:cinID",
      templateUrl: "app/contact/detail.html.tmpl",
      controller: "CinController",
      controllerAs: "controller",
      resolve: {
        email: ["$stateParams", "$spring", "socketio", function(e, t, v) {
          v.emit('getcontactinfo', t.data[0].Id);
          v.on('gotcinfo', function(z, i) {
            var v = z.[0].;
            for (var a = !1, n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
              if (t.data[0].cId === "marc")
                a = v[n];
              break;
            }
            return a;
          });
          // if I don't have a return here it doesn't work, i.e.:  return {"name":"Josh","email":"josh@email.en"},
        }]
```

How can I force the resolve attrs to use the socket.io value which is returned?

Comment: im a little confused as to why you are using socket io vs $http since you are essentially just querying some backend with an ID

Comment: I think $http is slow than socket.io , that why i use socket.io

Comment: But Thank, Atsisuab, i think $http is the best way , Thanks , i will set this subject resolved